# wkhtmltopdf binary is not found or not executable - Windows & CakePHP

Tags: php, windows, cakephp, wamp, wkhtmltopdf

I am using CakePHP on a WAMP stack. I have installed the [CakePDF plugin](https://github.com/ceeram/CakePdf) and am trying to use [WkHtmlToPdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) as the rendering engine.

If I run WkHtmlToPdf from the CLI it works perfectly, however when trying to generate a PDF from the CakePHP application I get:

> wkhtmltopdf binary is not found or not executable: C:\wkhtmltopdf
>   Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

The path is correct and I used the WkHtmlToPdf binary installer for Windows if that makes any difference. I'm not really sure what else to try? If I try a difference rendering engine like TcPdf it works fine (but isn't as good as WkHtmlToPdf hence why I want to use it.)

Comment: Is `C:\wkhtmltopdf` where the actual executable is located? Try running it yourself in cmd

Comment: Yeah it works as I have that in my PATH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this by including the full path to the wkhtmltopdf binary

```
Configure::write( 'CakePdf', array(
    'engine' => 'CakePdf.WkHtmlToPdf',
    'options' => array(
        'print-media-type' => false,
        'outline' => true,
        'dpi' => 96
    ),
    'margin' => array(
        'bottom' => 15,
        'left' => 50,
        'right' => 30,
        'top' => 45
    ),
    'binary' => 'C:' . DS . 'wkhtmltopdf' . DS . 'wkhtmltopdf.exe',
    'orientation' => 'landscape',
    'download' => false
)
```

);